# Simple implementation of Android C2DM required

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am trying to implement Android c2dm. I have looked into documentation and seen the jump note and chrome to phone samples that are provided...

But i couldnt really figure out the process. It would be great if i could simple implementation of c2dm where in when we send a request from server, it displays simple notification... Plz help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please take a look at my open source project at: http://github.com/geeknam/Push-Contacts
The server side is written in Python. If you are familiar with Python, the code would be very easy to digest. Good luck!

Comment: Great example, but quite complicated for my purposes. Tomas answer was more useful for me. But when I need something more complex I'll come back here. Just imho, google's use of AppEngine just confuses things for me when trying to understand the request flows.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this blog entry about writing a c2dm server in Python a little while back: http://www.tomasmalmsten.com/2010/11/c2dm-server-application/ It's pretty simple to follow and provides the most basic functionality for getting it to work.

Comment: I'm going to give it a try now... the google examples are needlessly complex imho