# C2DM Python framework

Tags: python

I need to implement client notification for android and I thought to use c2dm.
Is there any framework for c2dm in python ? Does anybody have experience with server side c2dm  in python ?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775732/simple-implementation-of-android-c2dm-required). I hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an existing library, but I also recently searched how to send notifications to my droid using Python, and I came throuht [this blog post](http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/) which explains how C2DM works and gives a sample Python implementation. I didn't test it yet, but I believe it could be useful as a base at least.

**EDIT:**

There is also [this site](http://nma.usk.bz/) which offers the ability to send C2DM notifications to your droid via their servers using an API, and there's even a [python library](https://github.com/uskr/pynma) to access it more easily.

**EDIT 2:**

To use NotifyMyAndroid, it seems you have to install their software on your phone (of I didn't understand how it works ^^)